# Java Class Reflection: init external class with wild card parameters

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have searched for the solution of this question 2 days long and now must ask it here :-( My Problem:

I have created new custom Java Class:

```
package my.app.test;

class Test extends Object {
    Test(){

    }

    public void print(){
        System.out.println("success");
    }
}
```

In another package i have:

```
package my.app.test2;

public class Test2 {
    Test2(Class<? extends Object> Test){

    }

    public void execute(Class<? extends Object> Test){

    }
}
```

Now i want to inflate Test2.class with Test.class as on of parameters:

```
package my.app.test;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Index {
    Index(){}

    static public void inflate(){
        ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        if(loader != null)
            try {
                Class<?> Test2 = Class.forName("my.app.test2.Test2", false, loader);
                if(Test2 != null){
                    Class<?>[] types = new Class[1];
                    types[0] = Test.class;
                    Method m = Test2.getDeclaredMethod("execute", types);
                    m.setAccessible(true);
                    try {
                        m.invoke(Test.class, new Test());
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

But i get error :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: my.app.test2.Test2.execute(my.app.test.Test)
```

If it's possible to do that?

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what you did wrong.  Your Test2 class does not have an `execute(Test)` method.  What it does have is an `execute(Class)` method.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Test2` class don't have method like `execute(Test)` but has `execute(Class)`. You should do `Test2.getDeclaredMethod("execute", Class.class)`.

Comment: I do `Test2.getDeclaredMethod("execute", Class.class)` -> look in types. But i the error is here: `m.invoke(Test.class, new Test());` must be `m.invoke(Test2.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance(), Test.class);`. Your answer was helpful and i have up voted.

Answer (score 0):

The generic type is removed at runtime in your case you have to use `Object` as type. See [Java Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) for details and [Baeldung](http://www.baeldung.com/java-type-erasure) for a better explanation on the topic.

Comment: This is nothing with type erasure. He was just used wrong parameter type.

Comment: You are right, he has to lookup the method  by using Class as  type instead of Test or Object. I think what he  still wants to achieve as this is still designed as a generic parameter is to lookup the method with a generic parameter. Also the question has been edited by now.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for helpful tips! I have changed and improved the code, added comments for better understanding.

**my.app.test.Test.java**

```
package my.app.test;

public class Test extends Object {
    public String string = "Hello! ";
    public Test(String value){
        string += value;
    }

    public Test(){

    }

    public void print(){
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

**my.app.test.Index.java**

```
package my.app.test;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Index {
    Index(){}

    static public void inflate(){
        ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        if(loader != null){
            try {
                Class<?> Test2 = Class.forName("my.app.test2.Test2", false, loader);
                if(Test2 != null){

                    Class<?>[] types = new Class[1];
                    types[0] = Object.class;
                    // Get method public void execute(Object object){}
                    Method m = Test2.getDeclaredMethod("execute", types);
                    m.setAccessible(true);
                    try {
                        // Invoke Test.class as Object
                        m.invoke(Test2.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance(), new Test("It works!"));
                    } catch (InvocationTargetException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    types = new Class[1];
                    types[0] = Class.class;
                    // Get method public void execute(Class<? extends Object> Test){}
                    m = Test2.getDeclaredMethod("execute", types);
                    m.setAccessible(true);
                    try {
                        // Invoke Test.class as Class
                        m.invoke(Test2.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance(), Test.class);
                    } catch (InvocationTargetException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**my.app.test2.Test2.java**

```
package my.app.test2;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Test2 {
    public Test2(){

    }

    public void execute(Object Test){
        System.out.println("public void execute(Object object){}");
        ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        if(loader != null){
            try {
                // Get method public void print(){}
                Method m = Test.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("print");
                m.setAccessible(true);
                try {
                    // Invoke Test.class with String parameter initialized inside Index
                    m.invoke(Test);
                } catch (InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void execute(Class<? extends Object> Test){
        System.out.println("public void execute(Class<? extends Object> test){}");
    }
}
```